# MySQL и SET NAMES 'utf8'

Tags: mysql, кодировка

В MySQL создается БД таким образом `CREATE DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8';`
В каких случаях нужно выполнять `SET NAMES 'utf8'` и для чего это нужно?

Comment: кстати, для тех, кто не в курсе. `utf8mb4` в mysql это **настоящий UTF-8**, а `utf8` это обрезанный трёхбайтовый, который выдаст ошибку если вставить 4-х байтовый символ, вроде  ( см. http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/supplementary-test.html )

Answer (score 3):

`SET NAMES utf8` используется, когда у вас сервер не настроен на прием данных в вашей кодировке (в данном случае UTF8).

Тогда ему нужно явно сообщить, что вы будете отправлять данные в кодировке UTF8 и не требуется дополнительная перекодировка данных из latin1 в UTF8 (по умолчанию он ожидает данные именно в latin1).

Для того, чтобы на сервере для кодировки соединения вместо latin1 установить UTF8 следует в my.cnf секции `[mysqld]` установить директиву `character_set_connection`

```
[mysqld]
...
character_set_connection=utf8
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

устанавливает кодировку *соединения*, т.е. кодировку, в которой *клиент*  обменивается данными с *сервером*.

Это необходимо делать потому, что стандартная кодировка *соединения* в вашей системе вполне может быть `latin1` - ещё хуже, когда она перестанет совпадать после переноса скрипта или обновления баз.

Сервер mysql сам проведет конвертацию данных, если *таблица* будет содержать данные в другой кодировке. Правда, это может привести к ошибкам, если, к примеру, записать в таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (`a` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL) COLLATE='cp1251_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

символ `▲`, которого в кодировке таблицы нет.

таблицы в базе могут быть в любой кодировке. отдельные поля в таблице также могут иметь свою кодировку.

Answer (score 0):

ребят, существует руководство по MySql,  которое говорит, что `SET NAMES` экивалентент вот этим трем командам:

```
SET character_set_client = charset_name;
SET character_set_results = charset_name;
SET character_set_connection = charset_name;
```